# c++: how to initialize std::mutex that has been allocated with malloc?

Tags: c++, initialization, malloc, mutex

```
// Example program
#include <mutex>

struct A {
 std::mutex m;
};

int main()
{
   A* a = (A*) malloc(sizeof(A));
   a->m = std::mutex();
}
```

this gives me

```
In function 'int main()':
11:9: error: use of deleted function 'std::mutex& std::mutex::operator=(const std::mutex&)'
In file included from 2:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/mutex:130:12: note: declared here
     mutex& operator=(const mutex&) = delete;
        ^
```

how do I properly initialize he mutex m?

The reason I'm using malloc and not new is because I'm using this code inside a global replacement of `new` and I don't want it to recurse back into the replacement.

Comment: It’s dangerous to use C++ features inside a replacement `operator new`. There is no guarantee that C++ features won’t themselves use `operator new`; if that happens the code can recourse infinitely.

Comment: @PeteBecker what about creating a `thread_local bool already_in_new_;` variable and setting it to true true when inside new, but first checking if it is already new and in that case just returning malloc memory? would that be safe?

Comment: If you’re in the middle of constructing the mutex that’s going to provide thread safety when that recursive call occurs, you don’t have anything to lock, so the code isn’t protected from calls from multiple threads.

Answer (score 5):

When you do

```
A* a = (A*) malloc(sizeof(A));
```

You don't actually have an `A` at the location `a` points to.  You just have enough memory allocated for an `A`.  What you need to do is use placement new on that pointer so that an `A` object can be initialized in that memory.  That looks like

```
new (a) A{};
```

Comment: using placement new will not recurse into my new replacement?

Comment: @user1282931 I don't believe it does since placement new is a library only function.  Let me do some double checking.

Comment: @NathanOliver [It's fine](https://wandbox.org/permlink/v93hOt2p0xwNGckT)

Comment: @user1282931 Actually, now that I'm looking more into this, you shouldn't need to call placement new.  The new operator should just return the raw storage.  The new expression that you call the new operator with should initialize the object for you.  I'll leave this for right now since it'll fix the code you have, but I don't think you need it in your global new replacement.

Comment: Is this more explicit version equivalent: `void *p = malloc(sizeof(A)); A *a = new(p)A{};` and how can one properly dispose of this object?

Comment: @Nathan, maybe I didn't express this correctly, but I don't want to return the memory for A, I want to allocate A (containing a mutex) as a side-effect of the replaced new operator. A is needed for some book-keeping